# How to change function reference field within method?

Tags: go

```
type FuncPtr func(int) int

func Foo(i int) { return i * i }

type Events struct {
  SomeFunc FuncPtr
}

type Top struct {
  events Events
}

func (self *Top) initEvents() {
  // This change works within this function, but
  // doesn't stick around after this method returns.
  self.events.SomeFunc = Foo 
}

func main() {
  var t := Top{}
  t.initEvents()
  t.events.SomeFunc == nil // True: Change in initEvents() doesn't stick
}
```

How can I make the change inside `initEvents()` method persist? That is, I want to change the value of the function reference `Top::Events::SomeFunc` within the `initEvents()` method and for that change to stick once the `initEvents()` method returns.

Comment: I'm afraid your code is working as expected: `t.events.SomeFunc` is not `nil` at all (check here: https://play.golang.org/p/s2da81Jnmg). Or am I wrong and the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: Seems to be working fine, just change the Foo func declaration to return int (`func Foo(i int) int { return i * i }`)

Comment: @tomasz ah, your test made me realize that it's something to do with how I'm actually calling it in my code (look at looping): https://play.golang.org/p/P_j4_szh2J

Comment: @Dess first loop is taking copy of `Top` and modifying the copy. Access the element directly (https://play.golang.org/p/F8h5LEkwZv)

Answer (score 0):

The code you have works with some minor corrections to make it compileable.

1. There's no package declaration at the top
2. You're not specifying an integer return type for your function Foo

I've included a full example of the code below for convenience and if you want to run this yourself you can do it at: https://play.golang.org/p/Ngu8FFiGrI

```
package main

import(
  "fmt"
)

type FuncPtr func(int) int

func Foo(i int) int {
  return i*i
}

type Events struct {
  SomeFunc FuncPtr
}

type Top struct {
  events Events
}

func (self *Top) initEvents() {
  // This change works within this function, but
  // doesn't stick around after this method returns.
  self.events.SomeFunc = Foo 
}

func main() {
  var t = Top{}
  t.initEvents()
  if t.events.SomeFunc == nil {
    fmt.Println("SomeFunc not set")
  }
  fmt.Println("6^2 =",t.events.SomeFunc(6))
}
```

Comment: The code itself was just an example, not tested for syntax. The real reason is because, in my own codebase, I'm using it like so: https://play.golang.org/p/P_j4_szh2J

Comment: I'd still like to know how to make the change stick in the version with the for-each

Comment: To do that you can change the array from []Top to []*Top.